# Can EWS be configured to prevent email bodies from be returned?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, impersonation

Is it possible to allow access to EWS such that a service account user, setup with the ApplicationImpersonation role, is able to retrieve metadata for emails but not the actual email body?

I know you can set up the API request such that email body is not included in the property set, but wondered if there is a way to explicitly restrict access to email bodies, either through configurations of EWS or access controls for the impersonating user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no per message property security in Exchange server.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Do you think it would be possible to alter any of the configurations of EWS (i.e. change the local WSDL) to achieve this?

Comment: No, you cannot configure something that does not exist.